# Relocking bootloader on Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 (ZB601KL/ZB602KL)

Tags: fastboot, bootloader

After a few dozen unsuccessful attempts to make TWRP recovery work and almost bricking my Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 (ZB601KL/ZB602KL), I gave up and decided to relock the bootloader. But this turned out to be a problem on its own. Rigorous googling didn't yield any solution. No fastboot command helped.

How to relock its bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon relock_bl.cmd file. After trial and failure with different command lines, I found the remedy. Here is what helped in my particular case.

```
fastboot -s !deviceId! flashing lock
fastboot -s !deviceId! flashing lock_critical
```